# Detect missing space after punctuation and space before punctuation

Tags: python-3.x, string, punctuation

I want to detect a missing space *following* a punctuation and an extra space *before* punctuation. I attempted to use a regex to match `[A-Za-z0-9][?.,:!][A-Z]` and `[A-Za-z0-9]\s+[?.,:!]`, but both of these return `None` when applied to the string `Something is in the air tonight.Or is it ?`.

```
import re

mystring = "Something is in the air tonight.Or is it ?"

missing_space_regex = re.compile('[A-Za-z0-9][?.,:!][A-Z]')
print(missing_space_regex.match(mystring))

extra_space_regex = re.compile('[A-Za-z0-9]\s+[?.,:!]')
print(extra_space_regex.match(mystring))
```

I realize that the `extra_space_regex` as above will not detect the case where the text begins with a punctuation, but I can handle that as a special case.

Comment: This is not your immediate problem. But in the second print you are using the first regex instead of the second one.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim: Thanks for pointing that out. Has been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) instead of `re`, you could take advantage of regex Unicode character classes, like `\p{P}` for a punctuation character:

```
import regex

mystring = "Something is in the air tonight.Or is it ?"

missing_space_regex = regex.compile(r'.*?\p{P}\S')
print(missing_space_regex.match(mystring))

extra_space_regex = regex.compile(r'.*?\s\p{P}')
print(extra_space_regex.match(mystring))
```

Outputs:

```
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 33), match='Something is in the air tonight.O'>
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 42), match='Something is in the air tonight.Or is it ?'>
```

**Or** if you do want to use your chosen punctuation characters and `re`:

```
punc = "?.,:!"

missing_space_re = re.compile(f".*?[{punc}]\S")
print(missing_space_re.match(mystring))

extra_space_re = re.compile(f'.*?\s[{punc}]')
print(extra_space_re.match(mystring))
```

Comment: The `re` test `missing_space_re = re.compile(f"[^{punc}]*?[{punc}]\S")` fails if there exists a correctly spaced punctuation prior to the one with the problem. For instance, no problem is reported with `"Something is in the. Air tonight.Or is it?"`.   Using `\s` at the end instead of `\S` resolves the issue in this test.

Comment: Hmm.. Seems to be failing in my actual test case.

Comment: @PeterGrill I don't know why I put the `[^{punc}]` there instead of `.`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: That is actaully _intentional_ text. I use the profile as a clipboard to keep text that I need often (SE should really provde some place to do that). Was using that for questions posted here regarding TeX. BTW, the updated version seems to work great.  Thanks.