# Fixing sentences: add space after punctuation but not after decimal points or abbreviations

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I work with a very messy text when sentences are not capitalised and punctuations are separated properly. I need to add spaces when missing after punctuations [.,:;)!?] but not in decimal numbers or abbreviations.

This is an example:

```
mystring = 'this is my first sentence with (brackets)in it. this is the second?What about this sentence with D.D.T. in it?or this with 4.5?'
```

This is where I've got so far.

```
def fix_punctuation(text):
    def sentence_case(text):
        # Split into sentences. Therefore, find all text that ends
        # with punctuation followed by white space or end of string.
        sentences = re.findall('[^.!?]+[.!?](?:\s|\Z)', text)

        # Capitalize the first letter of each sentence
        sentences = [x[0].upper() + x[1:] for x in sentences]

        # Combine sentences
        return ''.join(sentences)
    
    #add space after punctuation
    text = re.sub('([.,;:!?)])', r'\1 ', text)
    #capitalize sentences
    text = sentence_case(text)
    
    return text
```

Which gives me this output:

```
'This is my first sentence with (brackets) in it.  this is the second? What about this sentence with D. D. T.  in it? Or this with 4. 5? '
```

I tried methods suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63370816/detect-missing-space-after-punctuation-and-space-before-punctuation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127372/regexp-add-space-after-period-but-not-when-period-represents-a-decimal-or-letter) but they didn't work with my case.
Regex makes my brain hurt so I will really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want to ignore the periods inside numbers and period-separated single-letter chunks with an optional period right after.

Here is a code snippet that implements the logic I described above:

```py
import re

mystring = 'this is my first sentence with (brackets)in it. this is the second?What about this sentence with D.D.T. in it?or this with 4.5?'

def fix_punctuation(text):
    def sentence_case(text):
        # Split into sentences. Therefore, find all text that ends
        # with punctuation followed by white space or end of string.
        sentences = re.findall(r'(?:\d+\.\d+|\b[A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])*\b\.?|[^.!?])+[.!?](?:\s|\Z)', text)

        # Capitalize the first letter of each sentence
        sentences = [x[0].upper() + x[1:] for x in sentences]

        # Combine sentences
        return ''.join(sentences)
    
    #add space after punctuation
    text = re.sub(r'(\d+\.\d+|\b[A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])*\b\.?)|([.,;:!?)])\s*', lambda x: x.group(1) or f'{x.group(2)} ', text)
    #capitalize sentences
    return sentence_case(text)
    
print(fix_punctuation(mystring))
# => This is my first sentence with (brackets) in it. This is the second?
#    What about this sentence with D.D.T. in it? Or this with 4.5?
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/xZAk1s).

The `re.findall` pattern, `(?:\d+\.\d+|\b[A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])*\b\.?|[^.!?])+[.!?](?:\s|\Z)`, matches

- `(?:\d+\.\d+|\b[A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])*\b\.?|[^.!?])+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `\d+\.\d+` - one or more digits, `.`, one or more digits
  - `|` - or
  - `\b[A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])*\b\.?` -  a word boundary, an uppercase letter, zero or more repetitions of a period and an uppercase letter, a word boundary and an optional `.`
  - `|` - or
  - `[^.!?]` - a char other than `.`, `!` and `?`
- `[.!?]` -  `.`, `!` or `?`
- `(?:\s|\Z)` - a whitespace or end of string.

The `re.sub` pattern, `(\d+\.\d+|\b[A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])*\b\.?)|([.,;:!?)])\s*`, matches and captures into Group 1 those patterns that we want to skip, and then matches and captures into Group 2 some punctuation chars and then matches any zero or more whitespace chars (to make sure we only have a single space after them), and a custom logic is used in the replacement argument, in the lambda expression.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It doesn't capitalise the second sentence because an extra white space is added after `it.`. I guess I can remove extra spaces before applying capitalisation. But is it possible to add a space only if it is missing?

Answer (score 1):

You could use look ahead to check whether the character that follows the point is not a digit, and is not a character followed by another point (abbreviation). You would need to apply this only for the point, and treat the other end-of-line punctuation differently. But also there you should not inject a space between `!?`:

```
text = re.sub(r"(\.)(?=[^\d\s.][^.])|([,;:!?)])(?=\w)", r"\1\2 ", text)
```

The more scenarios you want to cover, the more complex it will become.

Comment: Doesn't work with my capitalisation function but I might rethink how I do this bit.