# Sentence case not working in specific examples

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex:

```
/(?:\d+\.\d+|\b[A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])*\b\.?|[^.!?])+[.!?…](?:\s|\Z)/
```

It changes the first letter in a sentence to uppercase (and avoids abbreviations like `N.B.C.` etc).

It works fine.

Example:

```
function sentence_case($text) {
    // Split into sentences. Therefore, find all text that ends
    // with punctuation followed by white space or end of string.
    preg_match_all('/(?:\d+\.\d+|\b[A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])*\b\.?|[^.!?])+[.!?…](?:\s|\Z)/', $text, $sentences);
    $sentences = $sentences[0];

    // Capitalize the first letter of each sentence
    foreach ($sentences as &$sentence) {
        $sentence = ucfirst($sentence);
    }

    // Combine sentences
    return implode('', $sentences);
}
```

But if a sentence ends in a quotation-mark, or similar, then it strips it.

Example string:

```
$text = 'first sentence. second sentence! "third sentence?"';
```

Results in:

```
First sentence. Second sentence!
```

When it should be:

```
First sentence. Second sentence! "Third sentence?"
```

See [ideone demo](https://ideone.com/ypeNbo).

How can I adjust the regex so it includes quotation-marks **and** any other sentence enders? Currently it's covering `.!?…`

Comment: The last `[.!?…]` requires one of these chars to be at the end of string or before a whitespace. If you plan to match a `"` after these chars, add it as an optional choice, `(?:\d+\.\d+|\b[A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])*\b\.?|[^.!?])+[.!?…]"?(?:\s|\Z)` (see [the PHP demo](https://ideone.com/mu0U3V)). This will also require a different approach to uppercasing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Actually, my code is a PHP conversion of [_your_ python code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67475575/1185126) coincidentally. Can you please write up an answer here with the suggested solution? PS. I fixed your original regex by including ellipsis character ´…´ as it didn't work in many various sentence ending cases. Maybe there is a regex solution targeting _all_ types of sentence enders...?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Did you get a chance to look into this? =)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your regex does not account for the (triple) dots. Besides, the `"` character can appear right before the `(?:\s|\Z)` pattern that requires a whitespace or end of string.

Thus, a possible solution is to

1. Include `…` into `[^.!?]` and `[.!?]` patterns
2. Add an optional `"` char before `(?:\s|\Z)`
3. Change the uppercasing code to a `preg_replace` that will turn the first found letter to upper case (since the `"` at the start of the match will invalidate your approach consisting in uppercasing the first character in the match.

And the pattern will look like

```
/(?:\d+\.\d+|\b[A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])*\b\.?|[^.!?…])+[.!?…]+"?(?:\s|\Z)/u
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XeT64k/1).

The code to turn the first letter to upper case will look like

```php
preg_replace_callback('/\p{L}/u', function($m) {return mb_strtoupper($m[0]);}, $sentence, 1)
```

where `/\p{L}/u` matches any Unicode letter and `mb_strtoupper($m[0])` will turn that letter to upper case.

Also, note that `[.!?…]+` has a `+` quantifier, which is helpful when there are several sentence end punctuation marks (like `?!`).

The [whole PHP demo](https://ideone.com/thNVXY):

```php
<?php
 
function sentence_case($text) {
    if (empty(trim($text))) return;
 
    // Split into sentences. Therefore, find all text that ends
    // with punctuation followed by white space or end of string.
    preg_match_all('/(?:\d+\.\d+|\b[A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])*\b\.?|[^.!?…])+[.!?…]+"?(?:\s|\Z)/u', $text, $sentences);
    $sentences = $sentences[0];
 
    // Capitalize the first letter of each sentence
    foreach ($sentences as &$sentence) {
        $sentence = preg_replace_callback('/\p{L}/u', function($m) {return mb_strtoupper($m[0]);}, $sentence, 1);
    }
 
    // Combine sentences
    return implode('', $sentences);
}
 
$text = 'first sentence. second sentence! "third sentence?"';
 
echo sentence_case($text);
```